# boost::asio - peeking into a socket buffer

Tags: c++, networking, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I use boost::asio::read (or may be the equivalent [async_read](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html)) to read some data from a socket.

Is it possible that I leave the bytes read in the underlying socket so that next time I call read on the socket I receive again that data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Simon said, you can't do it with `boost::asio::read()` (or `boost::asio::async_read()`).  However, for `read()` you could call `native_handle()` on the socket to get the socket descriptor and then use `::recvmsg()` with the `MSG_PEEK` flag.  Similarly, you could call `async_read()` with `null_buffers()` as the receive buffer and then use the `native_handle()`/`::recvmsg()` trick to peek the data.  Check out [this section](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) of the boost documentation for how to use null_buffers().

Comment: Thinking again l think will do anything to prevent using peeking. I only needed in order to peek for the first byte of a connected socket because that was interpreted differently by 2 different protocols (used as a marker in order to consider it's protocol A or it's protocol B), but reading platform implementation specific description from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192599 I realize that it's quite ineficient probably even for my case when I need only 1 byte.

Comment: Winsock applications that use one of the peek methods, with either recv/WSARecv(..., MSG_PEEK) or ioctlsocket(FIONREAD, ...), to obtain the amount of data in the receive buffer is highly inefficient because the system must lock the data and count it. As the system does this, it is likely that the real-time network will still attempt to fill the buffer with more data. Peeking also does not remove the data, which would allow the buffer to reach its storage limit. As a result, this closes down the network data-flow rate and makes the entire process of data transmission inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible - if you want a kind of **peek** you have to store the peeked bytes by your self.

Comment: Yes this is the recommended approach even on my specific case